# Data transferring from excel table to word table

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to find an answer to my problem. I am trying to create some python code for transferring data from an excel table to a word table. e.g. The row from the excel table should be copied from excel and be pasted in a certain column in the word table. Can anyone help me with that, please? Thank you

Comment: SO is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service; see [ask] and consider taking the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you'll need the [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) libraries. 
You should then be able to read the excel file by iterating over rows, and create a word table by using `table = document.add_table(rows=rows, cols=cols)`.

You can then fill in the table by using `row_cells = table.add_row().cells` and `row_cells[0].text = text`. I've linked the documentation for both modules above.

Comment: Thank you, Jeremiah! But it would be possible to do this with win32com.client. For any reason I can not intall openpyxl or python-docx. Please take in consideration that I have to move data cell by cell from excell to a table in word that is already defined. your help is much appreciated!